# How to create a program architecture for user preferences using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, architecture, preferences

I am trying to create a preference window for users, which they can manipulate (change preferences).
I want to implement it in a proper way so do you have any suggestions for a good code architecture? By the way I am using the MVVM pattern for C# with WPF.

Like, using a preferences class  in which all settings will be saved... or something like that.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encourage you to use some kind of MVVM framework.

Below I am presenting solution with MVVM Light - free MVVM framework.

1. Create new window for options for example OptionsWindow (.xaml & .cs)
2. Create ViewModel for your new Window for example OptionsWindowViewModel
3. In your main window create button with: Command={Binding CreateOptionsWindowCommand}, in your MainViewModel:

`public RelayCommand CreateOptionsWindowCommand
    {
    get; private set;
    }`

in your ctor

```
CreateOptionsWindowCommand = new RelayCommand(CreateOptionsWindowCommandExecute)
```

and function:

```
private void CreateOptionsWindowCommandExecute()
{
   OptionsWindow newOptionsWindow = new OptionsWindow();
   OptionsWindowViewModel vm = new OptionsWindowViewModel();
   newOptionsWindow.DataContext = vm;
   newOptionsWindow.ShowDialog();
}
```

All bindings in your new options window are binding now to OptionsViewModel.

To retrieve options and data you saved in OptionsWindow to your MainViewModel you can use Messanging implemented in MVVM Light. Messanging is used to communicate between classes.

Comment: yes thanks I forgot to tell that i am using this framework, i will try this out and report.

Comment: so I bind the, lets say preference items on the OptionsViewModel and send them via `Messenger` to my mainViewModel... is there a possibility to make the pereference object (in which all settings are saved) some kind of global? to access it in an easier way...

Comment: well you can consider creating OptionsViewModel not as a local variable in function. It could be your property in your MainViewModel. You can also find a lot of solutions of these kinds of problems in books about design patterns. (C# Design Patterns - O'Reilly is pretty good one).